# How to create pointer to UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Sorry for the noob question, but if I were to create a UITableViewController, I could create a pointer to the table by declaring:

```
UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
```

How would I do this if I were to create a UIViewController with a TableView created within it in storyboard with the view controller declared as data source and delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an `IBOutlet` to your view controller and connect it in your storyboard.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

This effectively replicates the standard `tableView` property that is supplied by `UITableViewController`.

Note, the `weak` property is assuming that the `tableView` is a subview of the view controllers `view`. If it isn't, the `tableView` should also be connected as the `view` IBOutlet in the storyboard. In that case `tableView` becomes an alias for `view`.

Answer (score 1):

follow this steps please:

1) Drag tableViewController into storyboard, place it in view controller that belongs to your UIViewController;

2) Add protocols in header of your class. Put it in interface line like this -  `@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>`

3)  Add property to header of your class - `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;`

4) Control+drag tableView on storyboard and connect it to DataSource and tableView delegate,and connect it to property `IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;`

5) Add cells, reuse identifiers to tableView, and class methods to implementation of your class.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to create an outlet for the table view in a `UITableViewController`. It already has a property `tableView` that you can access. It happens to point to the same object as the `view` property.

In reference to the other answer, note that you cannot move the table view away to become a subview of `view`, because they are the same. You would have to use the superclass `UIViewController` to have a setup like that.

This is documented in the [`UITableViewController` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007523-CH3-SW1).

Comment: i don't understand this point "It happens to point to the same object as the view property."

Comment: Also, I'm creating a ViewController with a tableview, not a UITableViewController, with no tableView to access.

Comment: The sentence you ask about means that the two properties point to the same machine address, i.e. the same object. The pointers are identical. Your question clearly asks about table view controller not view controller. Thanks for wasting my time.